# How Do I Create a DbContextFactory Within a Blazor Background Service?

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on my first Blazor Server application, which is also my first Entity Framework Core application. I am wanting to set up a background service which, once a day in the early morning, checks the database to see if any of a certain record type has been added with yesterday's date. If so, the relevant records are pulled, formatted, and then emailed to a stakeholder.

I have the EF, formatting, and emailing code working just fine when I trigger the report by manually visiting the page. The problem that I have is how to provide the background service with a DbContextFactory so that the EF and related code can execute.

Up to this point I've always used Razor-based dependency injection to inject the IDbContextFactory via an `inject IDbContextFactory<OurAppContext> DbFactory` at the top of the page, and then accessed the DbFactory via the `DbFactory` variable.

However, background services are (according to [this Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service)) set up through `Program.cs`, so I don't have access to Razor-based dependency injection there.

I have set up my background service (what I call the PhaseChangeReportService) as indicated in the above link, and it dutifully outputs to the console every 10 seconds that it is running with an updated execution count. I don't fully understand what's going on with the various layers of indirection, but it appears to be working as Microsoft intended.

I noted that the constructor for the background service takes in an ILogger as a parameter, specifically:

```
namespace miniDARTS.ScopedService
{
    public sealed class PhaseChangeReportService : IScopedProcessingService
    {
        private int _executionCount;
        private readonly ILogger<PhaseChangeReportService> _logger;
        
        public PhaseChangeReportService(ILogger<PhaseChangeReportService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;                        
        }            

        public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                ++_executionCount;

                _logger.LogInformation("{ServiceName} working, execution count: {Count}", nameof(PhaseChangeReportService), _executionCount);

                await Task.Delay(10_000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

I was (and am) confused that the constructor is never referenced within Visual Studio, but when I drop a breakpoint on its one line of code it is hit. I tried modifying this constructor's signature so that it took in an `IDbFactory<OurAppContext>` as well, so that whatever dark magic is allowing an `ILogger<BackgroundServiceType>` to come in for assignment to `_logger` might bring in a `DbFactory<OurAppContext>` as well, like so:

```
private readonly ILogger<PhaseChangeReportService> _logger;
private readonly IDbContextFactory<miniDARTSContext> _dbContextFactory;

public PhaseChangeReportService(ILogger<PhaseChangeReportService> logger, IDbContextFactory<miniDARTSContext> dbContextFactory)
{
    _logger = logger;                        
    _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
}
```

However, doing so just led to the constructor breakpoint being skipped over and not breaking, with no exception being thrown or any console output of any kind (i.e. the prior execution count console output no longer showed up). So, I gave up on that approach.

Here is the relevant section of Program.cs:

```
// Configure the database connection.
string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("miniDARTSContext");
var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 28));
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<miniDARTSContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<ScopedBackgroundService>();
        services.AddScoped<IScopedProcessingService, PhaseChangeReportService>();        
    })
    .Build();

host.RunAsync();
```

Here's IScopedProcessingService.cs:

```
namespace miniDARTS.ScopedService
{
    public interface IScopedProcessingService
    {
        Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

And here's ScopedBackgroundService.cs:

```
namespace miniDARTS.ScopedService;

public sealed class ScopedBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> _logger;
    
    public ScopedBackgroundService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILogger<ScopedBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;        
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is running.");

        await DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is working.");

        using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            IScopedProcessingService scopedProcessingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IScopedProcessingService>();

            await scopedProcessingService.DoWorkAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(ScopedBackgroundService)} is stopping.");

        await base.StopAsync(stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

I'm confident I'm misunderstanding something relatively fundamental here when it comes to services / dependency injection, but my Googling and review of past StackOverflow answers has not turned up anything I can run with.

Comment: [Polite] Why would you not do this in a normal service/scheduled Task?  It may be possible, but a Web Server is not really designed to do background scheduled processing.

Comment: I would want the scheduled task to run on one of our servers (not my workstation), and for security purposes our IT department does not want us running web browsers (to trigger a web page) on a server. I suppose I could create a new Windows service that runs on the server, but then I'd end up duplicating a LOT of EF Core-related code within that service. I view a Blazor background service as the least bad option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDbContextFactory is an interface that is used for creating instances of a DbContext. When you add it to your services on program.cs for Blazor (`services.AddDbContextFactory(parameters)`), it implements the IDbContextFactory for you. This allows you to use the `@inject IDbContextFactory<YourDbContext> DbFactory` at the top of your razor components and then within your code you can call the CreateDbContext method when you need to create an instance of the DbContext (ex. `using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext()`).

You can pass an injected DbContextFactory as a parameter from a razor component to a class, and then use that DbContextFactory in a method to create an instance of the DbContext ([see constructor injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)), but that still relies on the razor component to inject the DbContextFactory to begin with.

To create an instance of a DbContext independent of a razor component, you need to use the constructor for your DbContext. Your DbContext will have a public constructor with a DbContextOptions parameter ([this is required to be able to use AddDbContextFactory when registering the factory service in program.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)). You can use this constructor to implement your own factory. If you aren't sure which options to use, you can check your program.cs to see what options you used there.

```
public class YourDbFactory : IDbContextFactory<YourDbContext>
{
    public YourDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<YourDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Test"));

        return new YourDbContext(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

Once you've created your own implementation of the IDbContextFactory interface, you can then use it in your code independent of razor components - for example in the background service class.

```
YourDbFactory DbFactory = new YourDbFactory();
using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
```